# Does refresh token requires Expired JWT for creating new access token?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

In my recent encounter, I was trying to implement JWT Tokens storing securely in the Front-End.
What my previous approach is to store `access_token` as well `refresh_token` in sessionStorage which is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Now, when `access_token` expires, I'll call for `/refresh` endpoint to obtain a new `access_token`. Here I'm passing expired JWT into Authorization Header. The idea here is to protect your refresh endpoint and make sure only logged-in users ask for the token.

After that, we change the implementation to prevent XSS and CSRF. And followed this,
[LocalStorage vs. Cookies](https://indepth.dev/posts/1382/localstorage-vs-cookies)

which recommend, store your access token in memory, and store the refresh token in the cookie. so from FE, we can't access the cookie.(HTTPOnly cookie) and `access_token`

Now the real challenge is when the page refresh, we lose `access_token` as we stored it into in-memory, and API asks for Expired JWT token.

So my question is, does `/refresh` endpoint requires an expired JWT token, or is that a good practice to use the refresh token without JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

Access token in memory and refresh token in a cookie is a respected option for SPAs. There is an emerging standard called [TMI BFF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff) that is worth keeping an eye on, since it is expected to formalise the best practice.

The cookie should have properties in line with these:

- HTTP Only
- Secure
- AES 256 encrypted
- SameSite=strict

Use of the 'auth cookie' cannot also require an access token, since these use cases will not work for the client:

- User refreshes page
- User opens new browser tab

One option is to send an anti forgery token as well as the cookie, as described in the [OWASP Double Submit Pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). In the browser the anti forgery token would need to be stored in local storage in order for the above use cases to work. This is not 100% XSS safe, but nor is anything else in the browser.

Some code of mine uses this approach as part of doing the OAuth work in a back end API:

- [SPA Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts#L180)
- [OAuth Code in API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.webproxyapi/blob/master/src/core/services/authorizer.ts#L103)

Like quite a few people I am interested to see how SPA best practice evolves. It is worth mentioning also that some people recommend proxying all API calls via a 'back end for front end':

- It is currently considered more secure
- But it also adds complexity and perhaps reduces capabilities in some areas

Comment: Thank you for suggesting more options. I'll check it out.